# How to use UWP Graphics.Capture API without GraphicsCapturePicker?

Tags: uwp, directx-11, screen-capture

Is there a way to use UWP Graphic.Capture API to capture the screen without displaying GraphicsCapturePicker to the user?
I want my program to capture and record the screen without user intervention
Thanks,

In microsoft documentation Direct3D11CaptureFramePool and GraphicsCaptureSession are created by displaying GraphicsCapturePicker
to the user and using user selection (GraphicsCaptureItem) to create framePool and session

```
var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();

//show dialog box with the user and wait for user selection
GraphicsCaptureItem item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync();
Direct3D11CaptureFramePool framePool = 
Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.Create(...)
GraphicsCaptureSession session = 
framePool.CreateCaptureSession(item);
session.StartCapture();
```

is there a way to do this without the dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to capture your app's screenshot, you could use [Windows.Media.AppRecording namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.media.apprecording) APIs. With these APIs, you do not need the 'GraphicsCapturePicker' dialog.

I make a simple code sample for you:

```
AppRecordingManager manager = AppRecordingManager.GetDefault();
var status = manager.GetStatus();
if (status.CanRecord || status.CanRecordTimeSpan)
{
    var result = await manager.SaveScreenshotToFilesAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder,"screnshot",AppRecordingSaveScreenshotOption.HdrContentVisible,manager.SupportedScreenshotMediaEncodingSubtypes);
    Debug.WriteLine(result.Succeeded);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var item in result.SavedScreenshotInfos)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.File.DisplayName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(result.ExtendedError.Message);
    }
}
```

If you also want to capture other window's screenshot, then there's no other built-in UWP APIs for you. You would have to use 'GraphicsCapturePicker'.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'm looking for screen capture not just my app capture.

Comment: @nadavi If so, you would have to use `GraphicsCapturePicker`. You could try to submit a **'Feature Request'** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the microsoft samples here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture/ScreenCapture/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L219
There has a way to create the GraphicsCaptureItem instance by the hwnd

Comment: Please describe the essence of the linked solution here in your answer

Comment: @Maccesch sorry I don't know the essence, it is something about the Windows core layer. I just searching for something about the screen capture on Windows. And found the sample and this question. I hope I can help anyone who sees this question in the future.